# Unwind from UIViewController by swiping

Tags: swift, ios8

Unfortunately I didn't know what keywords I should search for about this topic. I wanted to know how you could program going back from a push segue not by pressing any button but by swiping from the left border of the phone such you could do in many programs such as WhatsApp.

I thought about using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` but I didn't know how to do that.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you perform the usual Push segue - either via Interface Builder or via `performSegueWithIdentifier`, you get this behavior for free so long as the app is running on iOS 7+. Any time you can navigate back from a push segue you can either tap the back button or swipe from the left edge. Nothing special is required to obtain that behavior, unless you're not using the Push segue (for example, a modal segue).

Comment: Yeah, that was too easy - wasn't aware of that ^_^ anyway, on some view controller I have swipe gesture recognizer to navigate through an array - when swiping from left, obviously the gesture recognizer's selector is called. In this case there's no way to use this behavior, is it?

Comment: By default both should be triggered. If you swipe within the screen it should navigate the elements in the "array", but if you swipe starting from the edge of the display it should begin the navigate back animation. I have a similar UI setup in my app and both work.

Comment: Actually it isn't working even if I add @oltman 's UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer - I have segues that are manually called, in the storyboard it's defined as a push segue

Answer (score 1):

As Joey said, if you're using a standard `UINavigationController` on iOS 7 or later, this functionality should be built in. However, if you should need this behavior outside of a normal navigation action, the [UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer_class/index.html) would be what you're looking for.